# Rails 4 and Devise : Allow email blank on certain conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, email, devise

I'm currently working on a system where the email is only required if the user is not a student and username is required if the user is a student.
So here is what I did in my model :

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :email, presence: true, unless: :student?
  validates :username, presence: true, if: :student?
end
```

This works fine on username attributes, but for the email, I'm still getting `Email cannot be blank` error. I guess Devise has it's own email validation rule.

How can I make this works, I mean overriding Devise validate presence rule on email?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Devise has an `email_required?` method that can be overrided with some custom logic.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :username, presence: true, if: :student?

  protected

  def email_required?
    true unless student?
  end
end
```

Comment: More specifically, this method is used by Devise's `validatable` "extension," so by over-riding this method you are obtaining more fine-grained control over the validations that Devise provides. You can just avoid the extension and build all validations yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I think Devise uses email as a key in its model.

`add_index :users, :email, unique: true`

If you used the generated devise migrations you could make the user_name the key with a migration.

`add_index :users, :user_name, unique: true` 
  `remove_index(users, column: users)` 
  `change_column :users, :email, :string, :null => true`